Infimum/Supremum: How could you have quickly completely this MCQ?

Consider sequence $$B=\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}:n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$$ What is the $\sup B$ and $\inf B$?
(A) $\sup B=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\inf B=-1$
(B) $\sup B=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\inf B=0$
(C) $\sup B=1,\inf B=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

This is from a multi-choice practice quiz problem set from my real analysis class. I managed to get the solution (C), but was quite slow. I would like to see how some more experienced mathematicians would have approached this question to quickly arrive the answer. Anything from thought processes to tricks (real-analysis/infimum/supremum specific or otherwise) would be much appreicated!

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I think it would be a good idea to separately look at odd and even values of $n$. Also, just from $n=1$ you can rule out answer option B.

Let $b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, so $b_n<0$ for odd $n$ and $b_n>0$ for even $n$. For even $n$, let $n=2k$ for some $k$, $b_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{\sqrt{2(2k)+1}}$ which decreasing, so the supremum is $b_0=1$ (1) or $b_2=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$ (2). For odd $n$, let $n=2k-1$, so $b_{2k-1}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{4k-1}}$, which is increasing and bounded above by $0$, so the infimum is $b_1=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
Note: The answer for supremum is (1) if the set of natrual numbers contains $0$, the answer is (2) if the set of natural numbers starts at $1$ (My professor taught me the latter fact). Here is a plotting of the sequence.
Please comment down if there are any errors.

Maybe this quiz is assuming that $0\in \mathbb{N}$?

Thank, I've changed my answer already

Take $n=1$, then we get $-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\in B$ so $\inf B\le-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. That rules out option B. Further,
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\ge\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\geq-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$
Hence, we must have $\inf B=-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.
Hope this helps. :)
